# Unable to scrape desired DIV - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping [this URL](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/sheraton/property/meetings/index.html?language=en_US&propertyID=1391) with `BeautifulSoup`.

I want to scrape every DIV after the **Our Features** heading:

```
if hotel_meetings_soup.select("div#contentArea div.highlightBox"):
    print(hotel_meetings_soup.select("div#contentArea")) # debug 1
    exit(0)
    for meeting in hotel_meetings_soup.select("div#contentArea div.highlightBox"):
        print("\n Feature start here\n")
        print(meeting)
        # Rest of code
```

All the DIVs have same class `highlightBox` but I dont know why The `debug 1` prints only the markup of the DIV which have

```
Number Of Guest Rooms:  500
Number Of Meeting Spaces:   29
Largest Meeting Space:  17,377 sq ft (1,614.28 sq.m)
```

in it but not others.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to, first, find the `Our Features` `h3` element *by text*, then find the appropriate next siblings using [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.starwoodhotels.com/sheraton/property/meetings/index.html?language=en_US&propertyID=1391'
response = requests.get(url, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
features = soup.find(text='Our Features')

for div in features.parent.find_next_siblings('div', class_='highlightBox'):
    print(div.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Weddings
Host a beautiful wedding in the Valley of the Sun with our spectacular views, lush ceremony lawns, and upscale ballrooms with pre-function space. Stellar catering and superb service ensure a amazing day. More >
...
Get Rewarded
Earn Starpoints® and eligible nights toward SPG elite status on your next meeting or event. More >
```

Comment: I am gonna give it a try ... but isnt it strange that I can scrape thise DIVs for many other hotels for example.
http://www.starwoodhotels.com/sheraton/property/meetings/index.html?propertyID=115
I can get all the required DIVs using the code I posted in my question but not for this hotel even those DIVs exist inside `contentArea `